# How to enable href to appear with certain condition. ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to enable users to edit their respective comments they have made on my project. What I would like to do is match the current user in session with the eval value of the user that has made the respective comment. Below is what I have done so far:

```
  <%  if (Session["user"] != null && Session["user"] == Eval("first_name"))
          {
               %>

       <a href="#">Edit</a>

       <%
           }
           else
           {

           }
            %>
```

However, it gives an error:

> 'Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control.'

Here's the full code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="r2" runat="server" OnItemCommand="r2_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>



    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>

    <%  if (Session["user"] != null)
          {
               %>
        <br />
       <asp:Hyperlink runat="server" ID="myLink" Text="Edit" Visible="false"></asp:Hyperlink>
       <%
           }
           else
           {

           }
            %>
           <br /> <%#Eval("title") %><br />
            By <%#Eval("first_name") %> <%#Eval("last_name") %> on <%#Eval("date") %><br />

    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>

    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater><br />
```

Any ideas on how to fix this or any better solutions that can be done?

Comment: The error states that you're trying to do this outside the context of a data-bound control.  Are you?  If so, what do you expect `Eval("first_name")` to do?  Why?  What is the condition you're trying to check in this `if` statement?

Comment: You could use a `HyperLink` control and set it's Visibility from code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eval only works when you're setting a bindable property on a server control.

To do something like this, you could either have a server control container, or make an asp Hyperlink control.

HTML

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat="server" ID="myLink" Text="edit" Visible="false"></asp:Hyperlink>
```

C#

```
if (Session["user"] != null && Session["user"] == myObject.first_name))
    myLink.Visible = true;
```

Comment: myLink cant be detected in the C# page as I'm trying to display the hyperlink within an Item Template of a Repeater, any ideas?

Comment: In the ItemDataBound event of your repeater (which fires for each repetition), do a FindControl to find the hyperlink.  Here is a good example.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx